# Splitting a list with a separator

Tags: python

I have written a function that gets two arguments: a **list** and **one value that is present in the list previously given** (sep). The purpose of the function is to split the given list and return multiple lists in list without the value that was specified in the second argument of the written fuction. So with def split_list([1,2,3,2,1],2) ---> result would be [[1],[3],[1]]. The functionality of spliting is good but the result keeps the second value of the function (sep) in the separated lists. I couldnt think of a way how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

```
def split_list(l, sep):
 occurence = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == sep]
 newlist=[]
 newlist.append(l[:occurence[0]])
 for i in range(0,len(occurence)):
  j=i+1

  if j < len(occurence):
   newlist.append(l[occurence[i]:occurence[j]])
  i+=1
 newlist.append(l[occurence[-1]:])


 return newlist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
def split_list(l, sep):
    nl = [[]]
    for el in l:
        if el == sep:
            nl.append([])
        else:
            # Append to last list
            nl[-1].append(el)
    return nl
```

Or with your method, by using the list of occurences:

```
def split_list(l, sep):
    # occurences
    o = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == sep]
    nl = []
    # first slice
    nl.append(l[:o[0]])
    # middle slices
    for i in range(1, len(o)):
        nl.append(l[o[i-1]+1:o[i]])
    # last slice
    nl.append(l[o[-1]+1:])
    return nl
```

Answer (score 2):

you can split your list with below list comprehension and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function :

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,2,1,8,9]
>>> oc= [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == 2]
>>> [l[i:j] if 2 not in l[i:j] else l[i+1:j] for i, j in zip([0]+oc, oc+[None])]
[[1], [3], [1, 8, 9]]
```

So for your function :

```
def split_list(l, sep):
 occurence = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == sep]
 return [l[i:j] if sep not in l[i:j] else l[i+1:j] for i, j in zip([0]+occurence, occurence+[None])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [list(x) for i, x in enumerate(l) if x != sep]